# higher {than on vs. than that on vs. than that of}

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which sentence seems more natural:

> 1. Tax burden on domestic companies is 30 percent higher than ***on*** international companies.
> 2. Tax burden on domestic companies is 30 percent higher than ***that on*** international companies.
> 3. Tax burden on domestic companies is 30 percent higher than ***that of*** international companies.

Comment: 'Those' is grammatically incorrect since it refers to a plural object. if you want a pronoun then you can use 'that'. Without a pronoun is ok too, especially if it's a newspaper heading. Stylistically, I would also keep the preposition constant and 'on' sounds better in my ears.

Comment: Needs a "the" before "tax burden".

Answer (score 1):

Although this is a matter of style, and hence subjective, the simplest way of looking at this is as an example of an elided parallel construction.

As such, the following would be the complete version:

> *The tax burden on domestic companies* is 30 percent higher than *the tax burden on international companies*.

And the following would be the shortened version:

> The tax burden on domestic companies is 30 percent higher than <s>*the tax burden*</s> on international companies.
>
> → The tax burden on domestic companies is 30 percent higher than on international companies.